# C++ MFC Libraries in Travis CI

Tags: c++, travis-ci

I want to compile a C++ Project with Travis-CI which uses MFC Libraries.

Is there a way to do this?

Here my .travis.yml

```
os: windows
language: cpp
env:
  - MSBUILD_PATH="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\MSBuild\Current\Bin"
install:
  - choco install visualstudio2019buildtools --package-parameters "--add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.Tools.x86.x64"
script:
  - export PATH=$MSBUILD_PATH:$PATH
  - MSBuild.exe -p:Configuration=Release -p:Platform=Win32 TBTA.sln
```

I get the following error:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets(429,5): error MSB8041: MFC libraries are required for this project. Install them from the Visual Studio installer (Individual Components tab) for any toolsets and architectures being used.

Comment: The error message tells you what to do. You need to install the MFC libraries.

Comment: Thanks, But how do i do this with travis-ci or choco?

Comment: The workloads are listed here: https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/visualstudio/install/workload-component-id-vs-build-tools?view=vs-2019 - I will try it with one of these.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution I need to add the correct package-parameters:

```
os: windows
language: cpp
env:
  - MSBUILD_PATH="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\MSBuild\Current\Bin"
install:
  - choco install visualstudio2019buildtools --package-parameters "--add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.Tools.x86.x64 --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.ATLMFC"
script:
  - export PATH=$MSBUILD_PATH:$PATH
  - MSBuild.exe -p:Configuration=Release -p:Platform=Win32 TBTA.sln
```